# Neewer FC-16 and Nikon D5500

Tags: nikon, nikon-d5500, sb-600

I have a Nikon D5500, SB-600 Speedlight and Neewer FC-16 wireless flash trigger and receiver system.
My camera and flash are both in manual. The trigger and receiver are both set to "flash". The green lights on them are flashing (so the batteries are fine). I still can't get it to work. The speedlight doesn't flash when I press the shutter on my camera!
Is the Neewer even compatible with the D5500? Any suggestions?!
Thank you!
/Arvind

Answer (score 1):

What mode  is the SB-600 set to? If it is set to "Slave", it will ignore the hot shoe of your trigger and wait until it senses a flash of light instead. You need to set the SB-600 to manual mode just as if it were attached directly to your camera's hot shoe so that it will respond to the trigger on the flash's hot foot.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My flash is set to manual, as is the camera. I'm now thinking that the Neewer isn't compatible, but I can't think of a reason why?!

Comment: @Arvind Are the transmitter on your camera's hot shoe and the receiver attached to your flash both set to the same channel?

Comment: Yes, same channel. I've actually fixed it though. This is gonna sound really silly, but it was a simple battery issue. Even though the lights were flashing on the triggers, I don't think the batteries had enough power! They were rechargeable 1.2v. I swapped for standard 1.5 and it works! Thank you for your input though!

Comment: The batteries powering the flash or the batteries powering the trigger/receiver?